# Output string variable in left hand side of assignment using LINQ

Tags: linq

I'm querying the Asp.NET MVC ModelStateDictionary using LINQ but I'm stuck on the following query:

```
public static DirectResult DirectValidation( this ModelStateDictionary state )
    {
        return new DirectResult()
        {
            Data = new
            {
                success = false,
                errors = from e in state
                        where e.Value.Errors.Count > 0
                        let errorName = e.Key
                        select new
                        {
                            errorName = e.Value.Errors.Select( x => x.ErrorMessage ).Concat( e.Value.Errors.Where( x => x.Exception != null ).Select( x => x.Exception.Message ) )
                        }

            }
        };

    }
```

In particular, I want the variable errorName to appear on the left hand side of the assignment. However, currently as things stand, what is getting output is:

```
"errors": [
  {
    "errorName": [
      "Code must be unique"
    ]
  }
]
```

How must I write the LINQ in order to get the result that I would like i.e something like

```
"errors": [
  {
    "Code": [
      "Code must be unique"
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the thing on the left hand side is a member name, and in statically-typed languages, member names are fixed. You could try to [create a type dynamically](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/06/Create-you-own-new-Type-and-use-it-on-run-time-%28C%29.aspx) or, if you have access to C# 4, use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx).

```
object CreateExpando(string field, object o)
{
    var e = new ExpandoObject();
    var d = e as IDictionary<string, object>;
    d[field] = o;
    return e;
}

select CreateExpando(errorName, e.Value.Errors.Select...);
```

Comment: Thank you I'll try that tomorrow.